# mysql Select rows with exclusive AND

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of `posts` and a table of `post_tags`
Here is my post table structure example:

```
post_id      int(11)
post_user    int(11)
post_title   text
post_content longtext
```

and this is my post_tags structure example :

```
post_id  int(11)
tag_id   int(11)
```

What I need is selecting all posts from `posts` table that have `tag_id` of 1 AND 2 at the same time, I've tried different joins without success.

example of post_tags table data :

```
post_id  tag_id
1        1
2        1
5        2
6        1
6        2
```

HERE for example my query should return post (from post table) whos id is 6, watch in the example post_id of 6 has tag_id 1 AND tag_id 2 NOT ONLY ONE OF THEM but BOTH at the same time.

Comment: " i've tried different joins without success."...Could you share your failure joins!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with aggregation:

```
select post_id
from post_tags pt
group by post_id
having sum(tag_id = 1) > 0 and
       sum(tag_id = 2) > 0;
```

If you want to see the actual information from `posts`, just join that table in.

EDIT (a bit of an explanation):

You have a "set-within-sets" query.  This is a common query and I prefer to solve it using aggregation and a `having` clause, because this is the most general approach.

Each condition in the `having` clause is counting the number of rows that match one of the tags.  That is, `sum(tag_id = 1)` is counting up the rows in `post_tags` where this is true.  The condition `> 0` is just saying "tag_id = 1 exists on at least one row".

The reason I like this approach is because you can generalize it easily.  If you want tags 3 and 4 as well:

```
having sum(tag_id = 1) > 0 and
       sum(tag_id = 2) > 0 and
       sum(tag_id = 3) > 0 and
       sum(tag_id = 4) > 0;
```

And so on.

Comment: it's not working, no result was returned, what i need is results from post table (a list of posts that have tags_ids 1 AND 2 simultaneously

Comment: @MoksyMosky . . . Are you sure there are posts that have both tags?

Comment: Yes i am sure at least one post has both, and also your query is not querying post table but it's querying post_tags table

Comment: I don't know what i was doing wrong but your query is working, can you explain me what the part having sum(.... is doing exactlly ? i didn't anderstand the expression : sum(tag_id = 1) > 0

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
SELECT post.*
FROM (SELECT T1.post_id
      FROM (SELECT * FROM post_tags WHERE 1 IN(tag_id)) T1
      INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM post_tags WHERE 2 IN(tag_id)) T2 ON T1.post_id = T2.post_id)
      T3
INNER JOIN post ON T3.post_id=post.post_id;
```

SQL Fiddle Link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/04f74/33

Comment: This query gives posts with tag_id 1 OR 2, what i need is posts with tag_id 1 AND 2 (at the samer time, not one of them only)

Comment: Can you give some examples of what the data in the tag_id field looks like?

Comment: Edited my question with example data

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
select q.* from (
      select  p.post_id as post_id from post_tags p 
      where p.tag_id=1 
      and exists (
            select 1 from post_tags p2 
            where p2.post_id=p.post_id 
            and p2.tag_id=2)
    ) as t
    inner join  posts q on posts_id=t.post_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.post_id, b.post_id, a.post_user, b.post_tags
from posts as a
inner join post_tags as b
where b.post_tags in(1, 2)
```

or

```
select a.post_id, b.post_id, a.post_user, b.post_tags
from posts as a
inner join post_tags as b
where b.post_tags =1 or b.post_tags = 2
```

Comment: Both request not working, both gives posts with tag_id 1 OR 2 What i need is posts with tag_id 1 AND 2 (at the same time)